# how to concat two column with hibernate queryover using linq

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I want to concat Employee firstname and lastname at select clause but it gives :

> Could not determine member from new <>f__AnonymousType0`1(name =
>   Format("{0} {1}", x.FirstName, x.LastName))

```
var returnData = UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.QueryOver<Employee>()
                 .OrderBy(x => x.Id).Asc
                 .SelectList(u => u.Select(x => x.Id).WithAlias(() => 
                                           businessSectorItem.id)
                                   .Select(x => new { name = string.Format("{0} {1}",
                                                x.FirstName, x.LastName) })
                                                .WithAlias(() => businessSectorItem.text))
                                   .Where(x => (x.FirstName.IsInsensitiveLike
                                                  ("%" + searchTerm + "%") ||
                                                x.LastName.IsInsensitiveLike
                                                  ("%" + searchTerm + "%")) &&
                                                  ( x.Account == null || x.Account.Id ==
                                                                           accountId))
                                  .TransformUsing(Transformers
                                                  .AliasToBean<SearchEmployeeItemDto>())
                                  .Take(limit)
                                  .List<SearchEmployeeItemDto>();
```

Comment: `string.Format` has a lot of different options that is too complex for most SQL engines to accomplish, try using `x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName`

Comment: i just tried your suggestion but it still gives the same error

Comment: It is also possible that query engine cannot understand anonymous type of `new { name = string.Format("{0} {1}",                                               x.FirstName, x.LastName) }`. I am not familiar with fluent-nhibernate, but maybe you can use string directly `string.Format("{0} {1}", x.FirstName, x.LastName)`? How will it interoperate with following `WithAlias` I don't know, but, nonetheless, it is a fair guess to check.

Comment: @EugenePodskal what do you mean by using string directly. If you mean that `Select(x =>  x.FirstName+" "+x.LastName)` it is also not working

Comment: Well, that was a fair, but wrong guess. Have you tried just to select `x.FirstName` or just `x.LastName`? Will it work?

Comment: yes it works fine when use only one property with select.the problem occurs on concat attemptions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `QueryOver` syntax would look like this:

```
// instead of this
.Select(x => new { name = string.Format("{0} {1}",
     x.FirstName, x.LastName) })
     .WithAlias(() => businessSectorItem.text))                                   

// we should use this
.Select(
    Projections.SqlFunction("concat", 
        NHibernateUtil.String,
        Projections.Property<Employee>(e => e.FirstName),
        Projections.Constant(" "),
        Projections.Property<Employee>(e => e.LastName)
    )).WithAlias(() => businessSectorItem.text)
```

We profit here from a sql function *concat*. We pass a `Projections.SqlFunction` into `Select()` statement and build part using some default/basic `Projections`

Comment: NHibernate is great! Enjoy it ;)

Comment: Entity forever.:) boss made me use NHibernate :/

Answer (score 7):

Or now even simpler:

```
using NHibernate.Criterion;

SelectList(l => l
  .Select(x => Projections.Concat(m.FirstName, ", ", m.LastName))
  .WithAlias(() => businessSectorItem.text))
)
```